# Project setup don't create service

Tags: service, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, project-setup

I am writing a service in C# using visual studio 2013.

I've added service installer and Project setup.
 (using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects).
I've created installer and installed it.

However, when I go to the windows services list My service doesn't appear there.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Did you add the installer class as custom actions to the Install, Uninstall etc nodes in the Custom Action view?

Comment: I added installer to the project, and then added Installer project to the main project using Project setup. This Project setup installer should install the output of the main project. The installation succeed, but I don't have the service in my services list.

Comment: You don't say that you added the custom actions - that is required. Just adding installers won't do anything unless you call them as custom actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Some of the properties of the installer were not set